# const function of const function in haskell

Tags: haskell

We have defined the following :

```
const a x = a
```

Now my question :
Why does the defined "variable" **a** in the following example evaluate as a **number** with the value 5 ?

```
a = const 5 const
```

Because if we look at the first part, namely the "const 5", we would have a result with the type of a function. But as a whole, the result is a number. Why ?

Comment: If we look at `(+) 1`, we have a result with the type of a function. But as a whole, `(+) 1 1` is a number. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It evaluates to 5 because `const` throws away its second argument, and just evaluates to its first. The first argument is 5, so that's what it evaluates to.

> Because if we look at the first part, namely the "const 5", we would have a result with the type of a function.

But that's not all the code, and only looking at the "first part" changes the meaning.

If you wrote only:

```
a = const 5
```

Then `a` *would* be a function since you're only partially applying `const`. In reality though, you're passing `const` as the second argument to `const`, fully applying the function, and allowing it to evaluate.

Answer (score 2):

You define:

```
const a x = a
```

this is short for:

```
const = (\a -> (\x -> a))
```

So a function (with one argument `a`) that results in a function (again with one argument `x`) that maps to `a`.

Now if we thus write:

```
const 5 const
```

we have written implicitly:

```
(const 5) const
```

If we work out the first `const`, we see:

```
   ((\a -> (\x -> a)) 5) const
-> (\x -> 5) const
-> 5
```

So your defintion of `const` simply *ignores* the second argument. Regardless of what it is (a function, a number, a character, etc.), it will return the first argument (here `5`), and `5` has type `Num a => a` (it can by any *number* type).

In case you would have written `const 5` however, you would obtain:

```
   const 5
-> (\a -> (\x -> a)) 5
-> (\x -> 5)
```

which is a function that takes any type of input `x`, and maps it on a number `5`.